# Registration failure to firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I managed to write this code for my registration platform, and when I test the android application, it gives me the response of registration failure that occurs when incorrect data is posted.

```
public class mainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText userFullname, userEmail, userIDnumber, userTelephonenumber, userUsername, userPassword, userConfirmpassword;
    private Button signButton;
    private TextView userLogin;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupUIViews();

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        signButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (validate()){
                    //upload the data to the database
                    String user_email = userEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                    String user_password = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_email, user_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, "You have registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(mainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, "Registration Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        userLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(mainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupUIViews() {
        userFullname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserFullname);
        userEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserEmail);
        userIDnumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserIDnumber);
        userTelephonenumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserTelephonenumber);
        userUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserUsername);
        userPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserPassword);
        userConfirmpassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserConfirmPassword);
        signButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSign_up);
        userLogin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvUserLogin);
    }

    private Boolean validate() {
        Boolean result = false;

        String name = userFullname.getText().toString();
        String email = userEmail.getText().toString();
        String IDno = userIDnumber.getText().toString();
        String tel = userTelephonenumber.getText().toString();
        String uname = userUsername.getText().toString();
        String pass = userPassword.getText().toString();
        String cnfpass = userConfirmpassword.getText().toString();

        if (name.isEmpty() && email.isEmpty() || IDno.isEmpty() || 
            tel.isEmpty() || uname.isEmpty() || pass.isEmpty() ||
            cnfpass.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill in the empty fields to register", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Log the `user_email` & `user_password` before the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method. You might get a hint of what you should do next. Comment down the logs to help us answer your question

Comment: Registration failure with what error?

Comment: @Sagar Am finding it hard to clearly understand what you are saying

Comment: @AlexMamo  'Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, "Registration Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }' and yet when i register on the virtual device correctly it displays this message.

Comment: Use `android.util.Log` (Log Utility) to log & check the value of `user_email` & `user_password`. There are chances that those variables can be `null` which leads to a Failure while Signing Up. Also, try the app on an actual device to see if the results match.

Comment: @Sagar I'm a learner in using android studio so could you explain to me where to put this Log Utility

Comment: @RoyRasgee Read the given [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat). Google how to do it man. Every tiny thing can't be explained on Stack Overflow

Comment: @Sagar Thank you so much